# Facebook access tokens format

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I am manually building a login system to my application using facebook. Following this [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.1) I am told to do some get requests to obtain user information. Echoing an returned token I obtain this

(**using FILE_GET_CONTENTS()** ):

```
$access_token = "graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=$client_id&redirect_uri=$redirect_uri&client_secret=$client_secret&code=$user_code") :
```

**echoing $access_token:**

> access_token = CAAKlMMCiHp(...)ZByh3faLzh **&expires=5125282**

or this for an **app_token** ("graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=$client_id&client_secret=$client_secret&grant_type=client_credentials") :

**echoing $app_token:**

**access_token = 744(...)90|vZU2(...)e0-s**

The last one to obtain the user information that I have to do is this:

```
$last_one = "graph.facebook.com/debug_token?access_token=$access_token&app_token=$app_token";
```

Check above that I have to use **$access_token** and **app_token**. The problem is that when I `echo $access_token` what I obtain is **literally** ***access_token = xxxx...***, including the "access_token" and the "=" sign instead of just the token.
So, when I try to do my last request (**$last_one**) I have (with variable replacement):

> $last_one = "graph.facebook.com/debug_token?**access_token=access_token=xxx**&**app_token=app_token=xxxx**";

To avoid this I removed the first "access_token=" and "app_token=" and successfully eliminated the duplicate. Unfortunately I now have **access_token=xxx&access_token=xxx** because although one is literally for access and another is to the app both are treated as access_token and their echo also explicits "access_token =" as shown above.

My question is if this is supposed to happen and how can I get only the token? I find it kind of ridiculous to have the need of using substr() just to eliminate the first part of the token **"access_token ="**. Am I supposed to reach the token by a getter part of file_get_contents()? And should I include **&expires=xxxx** of the first token in the last request? Please refer and shortly read the [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.1) from "Confirming identities" to understand what is my dilema. I hope I made myself through, thank you very much!

Comment: You could just use Facebook PHP SDK v4 and it will do everything for you

Comment: Have you tried using `parse_str` to parse the access token when it is returned to you?